# how/where to write custom lambda authorization code in aws?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-lambda, aws-api-gateway

I am following an example here (https://github.com/aws-samples/serverless-patterns/blob/main/apigw-lambda-authorizer/template.yaml ) to create an REST based API .I want to create a custom lambda authorizer , which i can use to validate token ( string based ) which is passed in the header as such

```
Authorization: Bearer <some_token>
```

in the aws example above (link provided) . i see a tokenizer.js  and assuming the tokenizer.js will validate the token, i don't see how it is doing that. I have copy/pasted sample code below.

if i wanted to call to a database and then validate the token being passed , i would assume i need to put the logic here, but i don't see in the example.

```
exports.handler = function(event, context, callback) {
    
    console.log('Received event:', JSON.stringify(event, null, 2));

    sleep(milliseconds).then(() => {
        console.log('Slept for ' + milliseconds + ' milliseconds');
        
        var user = 'user'
        var token_name = 'authorizationToken'
        var token = event[token_name];
        
        console.log('Token: ' + token);
        
        switch (token) {
            case 'Bearer allow':
                console.log('Returning Allow');
                callback(null, generatePolicy(user, 'Allow', event.methodArn));
                break;
                ...
        }
    })
};
var generatePolicy=fucntion(principalId, effect, resource ){
...
```